# Occurrence of some event by ID and Date

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
<ID>     <Event>      <Date>
1         Ate          2021-01-01
1         Drank        2021-01-01
1         Ate          2021-02-23
2         Ate          2021-01-02     
2         Ran          2021-01-02
2         Ate          2021-02-23
3         Drank        2021-01-01
3         Ran          2021-02-23
```

What I am hoping to determine is whether an Event took place for each group of IDs on a certain date. In this case, I want to determine which ID "Ate", period, within each group of dates.

An expected result would be a table that looks like:

```
<ID>     <Event>      <Date>            <Outcome>
1         Ate          2021-01-01       Yes
1         Drank        2021-01-01       Yes
1         Jumped       2021-02-23       No
2         Ate          2021-01-02       Yes
2         Ran          2021-01-02       Yes
2         Ate          2021-02-23       No
3         Drank        2021-01-01       No
3         Ran          2021-02-23       No
```

I hope this makes sense, thank you for your help!

Comment: hi akrun, happy you're here actually you have the most answers I've seen related to R! Essentially, there are a series of events (ate, ran drank, jump, etc) that can take place on a given day. On some days, multiple events can take place. I would like to determine whether "Ate" happened within the group of activities on a given day.

Comment: Thanks, I posted a solution below.  Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to check whether 'Ate' occured along with another 'Event' for each 'ID', 'Date', do a group by 'ID', 'Date', check if the number of rows (`n()`) are greater than 1 and (`&`) 'Ate' is found `%in%` 'Event'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, Date) %>% 
  mutate(Outcome = c("No", "Yes")[(n() > 1 & 'Ate' %in% Event) + 1]) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#     ID Event Date       Outcome
#  <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr>  
#1     1 Ate   2021-01-01 Yes    
#2     1 Drank 2021-01-01 Yes    
#3     1 Ate   2021-02-23 No     
#4     2 Ate   2021-01-02 Yes    
#5     2 Ran   2021-01-02 Yes    
#6     2 Ate   2021-02-23 No     
#7     3 Drank 2021-01-01 No     
#8     3 Ran   2021-02-23 No
```

---

In order to check for cases where there are `duplicate` 'Ate' and no other values per group, we can use `n_distinct` (instead of `n()`) i.e. checking for number of distinct elements of 'Event' to be greater than 1

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, Date) %>% 
  mutate(Outcome = c("No", "Yes")[n_distinct(Event) > 1 &
           'Ate' %in% Event) + 1]) %>%
  ungroup
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Event = c("Ate", 
"Drank", "Ate", "Ate", "Ran", "Ate", "Drank", "Ran"), Date = c("2021-01-01", 
"2021-01-01", "2021-02-23", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-02", "2021-02-23", 
"2021-01-01", "2021-02-23")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: This worked! can you please help me understand the following syntax: mutate(Outcome = c("No", "Yes")[(n() > 1 & 'Ate' %in% Event) + 1])

I kind of get it, but the n()>1 and +1 throw me off

Comment: @the_witch_dr the `(n() > 1 & 'Ate' %in% Event)` returns a boolean (`TRUE/FALSE`) Adding 1 to it change the TRUE (1) to 2 and FALSE (0) to 1.  which is used as position index for the vector c`("No", "Yes")` i.e. whereever we have 2, it is replaced with "Yes" and for 1, with "No".  In `R`, indexing starts from 1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[,Outcome := c("No","Yes")[1+isTRUE(Date==Date[Event=="Ate"] & .N>1)],.(ID,Date)]
```

giving

```
   ID Event       Date Outcome
1:  1   Ate 2021-01-01     Yes
2:  1 Drank 2021-01-01     Yes
3:  1   Ate 2021-02-23      No
4:  2   Ate 2021-01-02     Yes
5:  2   Ran 2021-01-02     Yes
6:  2   Ate 2021-02-23      No
7:  3 Drank 2021-01-01      No
8:  3   Ran 2021-02-23      No
```